# Use cases for "mdadm --create" vs. "mdadm --build"?

Tags: raid, mdadm

From the mdadm man page, --build section:

> This usage is similar to --create. The difference is that it creates a legacy array without a superblock.

^^ So no superblock with --build.  10-4.  This is followed by:

> With these arrays there is no difference between initially creating the array and subsequently assembling the array, except that hopefully there is useful data there in the second case.

^^ I'm confused by this statement.  Can anyone rephrase?

What would be a use case for --build, instead of --create?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create arrays in legacy format, you would use --build. This may be because you have to connect this array to an old system which lacks metadata/superblock support.

You most likely want to use `--create` for common use cases.

**To clarify the confusing text:**

As there is no metadata/superblock on the disks, arrays created by `--build` cannot store any *additional* data about the array.
If you choose to work with arrays *without* metadata (by using `--build`) the applied operation is the same even if you have brand new disks or you have a previously used array. The lack of metadata prevents any possible detection.

In arrays with metadata, you create a new array on new disks with `--create` and subsequent uses of the array is conducted by `--assemble`, which uses the metadata on the disk to verify status of the array and correctness of the assembly.

Lacking the distinction with first time initialization and regular assembly process, `--build` option would create an array when you first call it on some new disks. Then you probably use the disk and write some useful data on it. On your next `--build` action, you expect to see the previously recorded data after the build operation, so you *hopefully* find some useful data on the array in succeeding invocations of `--build`

Comment: Correct.  But I think the OP is asking *Why* would you want to do this?

Comment: I assume the only use case is to create arrays to connect to older systems.